# How to do an ad-hoc build (iOS platform with a distribution certificate/profile) in Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I used cordova 4.1.1 and recently update to Cordova 7. I am unable to do an ad-hoc build the app with a production provisioning profile. I want to create the ipa using terminal commands.

```
ionic cordova build ios --device --release --buildConfig=./platforms/ios/build.json
```

Build config file is

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "{{Team ID}}",
      "packageType": "development",
      "provisioningProfile": "{{development provisioning profile}}",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "{{Team ID}}",
      "packageType": "ad-hoc",
      "provisioningProfile":"{{distribution provisioning profile}}",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Error is,

```
Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "XXXXX Dist Profile" doesn't include signing certificate 
"iPhone Developer: Sachitra Malwatte (XXXX)".
```

I am confused. Why we need a development certificate if we are building an ad-hoc build?

How to build using a production certificate and a distribution profile?
Development certificate cannot be added to a distribution profile.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.

I am using Xcode 9.2.

Latest Cordova docs says to use `"codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer"` even for release builds.
But looks like we have to use `"codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution"`

ad-hoc build worked with this build config

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "developmentTeam": "{{Team ID}}",
      "packageType": "development",
      "provisioningProfile": "{{development provisioning profile}}",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "developmentTeam": "{{Team ID}}",
      "packageType": "ad-hoc",
      "provisioningProfile":"{{distribution provisioning profile}}",
      "buildFlag": [
        "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
        "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO",
        "LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = \"@executable_path/Frameworks\""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Wasted good amount of time to figure this out :(

Comment: "iPhone Developer" is for using automatic signing, but as you are providing the provisioning profile it tries to use the not automatic signing, so it needs "iPhone Distribution" instead. If you remove the provisioning profile line it should work fine with "iPhone Developer". Also, those build flags are examples to show that you can add build flags in the build.json file, but you probably don't need them.